# Fill table column from mysql depending on value

Tags: mysql, html-table

I have a mysql table looking like this:

```
+------+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| id   | name  | RowSZ | TimeSZ   | DateSZ     | 
+------+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| 1    | namex | 2     | 12:00:00 | 2018-06-29 | 
+------+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| 2    | namey | 1     | 10:00:00 | 2018-06-30 |
```

Now I want to fill a html table which should look like this:

```
+-------+----------+----------+------------+
| name  | Timerow1 | Timerow2 | DateSZ     | 
+-------+----------+----------+------------+
| namex |          | 12:00:00 | 2018-06-29 | 
+-------+----------+----------+------------+
| namey | 10:00:00 |          | 2018-06-30 |
```

The Timerow1 and Timerow2 are filled depending on the value "RowSZ".

My SQL query right now:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DateSZ, '%d-%m-%y') AS DateSZ FROM table1 ORDER BY DateSZ ASC";
```

How can I fill the two rows Timerow1 and Timerow2 correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` to handle the two cases.

```
SELECT name, NULL AS TimeRow1, TimeSZ AS TimeRow2, DateSZ
FROM yourTable
WHERE RowSZ = 2

UNION

SELECT name, TimeSZ AS TimeRow1, NULL AS TimeRow2, DateSZ
FROM yourTable
WHERE RowSZ = 1

ORDER BY DateSZ
```